# Theano installation, nvcc not in the path

Tags: python, installation, theano, nvcc

I have installed theano on windows7,64bit on  winpython using their guide http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html and I thought it worked since when I ran their first example I did have the expected results and no errors. I wanted to go ahead and install the part: **Configure Theano for GPU use** but when I runned again it  I had this in the python console:

```
runfile('C:/Users/PS/Desktop/prova theano.py', wdir='C:/Users/PS/Desktop')
ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): nvcc compiler not found on $PATH. Check your nvcc installation and try again.
ERROR:theano.sandbox.cuda:nvcc compiler not found on $PATH. Check your nvcc installation and try again.
NP time: 0.156000[s], theano time: 0.181000[s] (times should be close when run on CPU!)
Result difference: 0.000000
```

the .theanorc file I am using is:

```
[global]
device = gpu
floatX = float32

[cuda]
root = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5

[nvcc]
flags=-LC:\SciSoft\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\python-2.7.9.amd64\libs
compiler_bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin
```

and I added it in C:\SciSoft\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\settings as I understood from the guide.

By the way, I checked the C:\SciSoft\env.bat and when I write **where nvcc** it says not file found instead I have no problems with the other checkings.  Is that because I haven't an NVIDIA card? I am totaly lost.Any help? Thank you

Comment: `Is that because I haven't an NVIDIA card?` CUDA is made by nvidia for nvidia cards. Only OpenCL is ought to work with "all" gpus.

Comment: Oh I understand! But if I don' t want to use the GPU  is theano correctly installed or can I have some troubles after bacause the GPU feature is one of the most important? I had some problem using lasagne ( neural network) and for this reason I checked this thing. And in case I will download OpenCL is there a guide that I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theano is designed to work (almost) identically on both CPU and GPU. You don't need a GPU to use Theano and if you don't have a Nvidia GPU then you shouldn't try installing any GPU-specific stuff at all.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I tried with the simple pipi install theano  without the GPU stuff and it worked but I have the same problem as before in lasagne so maybe it wasn't the problem. I will open another issue and I will accept your reply. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

aleju, if you don't want (or can't) use theano with GPU, you just need to change .theanorc to use only cpu. This will not cause any problem, except for poor performance.

```
[global]
device = cpu
...
```